# Cross compiling for several systems at once

Tags: libraries, cross-compiling

Question: How do make a single make file to compile several different systems, environments, and sets of libraries at once?

---

Info:

I'm a student and as such most of my work is done for the sake of learning how these things work. Right now I'm building a game engine from the ground up. I'd like to be able to make it cross platform in terms of OS, but also for different environments. My target environments are both 32 and 64 bit (my desktop as well as my netbook), with a graphics card and with mesa, and linux and windows. so overall it should out put 8 binaries.

I'm still very new to make, as well as the whole concept of cross compiling. I imagine that the process of compiling more than 1 binary isn't hard. but where I'm kind of stuck is how do i get it to attach the right libraries? The Ubuntu Linux vs the WinAPI libraries, 32bit vs 64bit libraries. etc etc. Is it even possible to get libraries in such a manner?

If you need me to clarify further I can. Thanks.

Addendum: Basically I want to know how to compile headers for drivers i may not have. for example. I want to compile all the files on my netbook, including the ones for openCL, I don't want to run them, as my netbook has no GPU, I just want to compile. conversely, I want to use my desktop compile for my netbook which uses ocelot and mesa for its gpu dealings, but my desktop does not have mesa or ocelot on it. that sort of thing. Thanks.